# How do I copy data from range of one book to range in another book?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to copy values from the workbook "Consulting-for Paracon_aax.xls" for a range "E24" to "Q24" to a workbook named "2014 - XPERT.xlsm" on a range "E9" to "Q9" in a sheet named Delivery.

This is what I've come up with.

```
Sub UpdateLinks()

'open the source workbook and select the source sheet
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\desmondm\Desktop\Consulting-for Paracon_aax.xls"

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

' copy the source range

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E24").Select

Selection.Copy

' select current workbook and paste the value at E9
Workbooks("2014 - XPERT.xlsm").Activate

Sheets("Delivery").Select

Sheets("Delivery").Range("E9").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

My macro only copies cell E24 from the Consulting-for Paracon_aax.xls to E9 in the Delivery sheet within the 2014 - XPERT.xlsm workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, I consolidated a bit for you, but basically you need to specify the full range of cells to copy (previously you were only copying `E24`.

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wbDestination As Workbook

'open the source workbook and select the source sheet
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open( _
    Filename:="C:\Users\desmondm\Desktop\Consulting-for Paracon_aax.xls")

'Set the destition workbook variable
Set wbDestination = Workbooks("2014 - XPERT.xlsm")

'copy the source range
wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E24:Q24").Copy

'paste the value at E9
wbDestination.Sheets("Delivery").Range("E9:Q9").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

And, a word to the wise :) it is tempting to use `Select` and `Activate` methods -- especially when you are new to VBA, because that is how the macro recorder captures your actions, but 99% of the time these are unnecessary, and it's more efficient/better to just use object variables and explicitly refer to them, rather than relying on `Selection` and `ActiveWorkbook` or `ActiveCell`, etc.